# How to autocomplete all inputs

Tags: php, jquery, database, forms

I have a form

```
<form name="form1" id="form_cont" method="post" action="creaza.php">
    <label for="idno">IDNO</label>
    <input type="text" name="idno" id="idno" value="">

    <label for="tip_persoana">Tip Persoana</label>
    <label for="first_name">Nume</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <label for="last_name">Prenume</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
...
```

When I complet field id="idno" jQuery it showing me autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#idno').autocomplete(
        {
            source: "autocomplet.php",
            minLength: 3
        });
    });
```

If I select one of this autocomplet, another fields (last_name, first_name...) whill be complet automatically from database and they will be disabled.

Comment: You'd have to create custom function for it.

Comment: I didnt understand your question. Please elaborate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete is for **fields**, not for **forms**. What you are trying to do is easily possible with jquery but this is not what **[Autocomplete UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)** was designed for. You can write custom jquery AJAX request for that. You can even use the autocomplete ui and parse the returned data and fill certain fields of the form but autocomplete itself will not do that for you

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery ui library

```
$('.form-control').each(function(i, e) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: url,
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log(ui)
            return false;
        },
    })
})
```